# TFS baseless merge

Tags: tfs, merge

I am merging two branches which do not have a parent child relationship. I have started with a single file to test if the merge is working properly before the actual merge. I am using tfs baseless merge in order to do this.The following is the command:

Tf merge /baseless C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Test\CreateDescription.aspx.cs C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Test1\CreateDescription.aspx.cs /recursive

Changes have been done in both the files. However in the resolve conflict dialog box I only see two options
1) Keep the changes in the target branch
2) copy code from source branch

Merge changes in merge tool is greyed out. What should I do in order to enable this option. I want to manually merge changes in the both the branches.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to check out the file you want to be the target (i.e `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Test1\CreateDescription.aspx.cs`) and then use an external merge tool to merge the changes. I'm a big fan our [SourceGear Diffmerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/), mainly because it's free (as in beer). This will allow you to merge the files and resolve the conflics.

Once you've done this, you could run the baseless merge to establish the merge relationship between the branches and tell the merge tool in TFS to keep the changes in the target. You can also tell [TFS to use DiffMerge as it's merge tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) which might get rid of the problem all together.